# Django unable to update model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

i have the following function to override the default save function in a model match

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   if self.Match_Status == "F":
        Team.objects.filter(pk=self.Team_one.id).update(Played=F('Played')+1)
        Team.objects.filter(pk=self.Team_two.id).update(Played=F('Played')+1)
        if self.Winner !="":   
          Team.objects.filter(pk=self.Winner.id).update(Win=F('Win')+1, Points=F('Points')+3)
        else:
            return
   if self.Match_Status == "D":
        Team.objects.filter(pk=self.Team_one.id).update(Played=F('Played')+1, Draw = F('Draw')+1, Points=F('Points')+1)
      Team.objects.filter(pk=self.Team_two.id).update(Played=F('Played')+1, Draw = F('Draw')+1, Points=F('Points')+1)
   super(Match, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am able to save the match model just fine but Team model does not seem to be updating at all and no error is being thrown. am i missing some thing here ?

Comment: As Daniel says, there's nothing that jumps out as wrong, but we really don't know anything about your code as a whole. It would be best if you can provide a complete simplified example. See: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html (Jon wrote that in the context of C#, but it applies to any language.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in ur admin.py

```
def save_model(self, request ,obj ,form,change):
   if obj.Match_Status == "F":
    Team.objects.filter(pk=obj.Team_one.id).update(Played=F('Played')+1)
    Team.objects.filter(pk=obj.Team_two.id).update(Played=F('Played')+1)
    if obj.Winner !="":   
      Team.objects.filter(pk=obj.Winner.id).update(Win=F('Win')+1, Points=F('Points')+3)
    else:
        return
     if obj.Match_Status == "D":
    Team.objects.filter(pk=obj.Team_one.id).update(Played=F('Played')+1, Draw = F('Draw')+1, Points=F('Points')+1)
      Team.objects.filter(pk=obj.Team_two.id).update(Played=F('Played')+1, Draw = F('Draw')+1, Points=F('Points')+1)
     obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing obviously wrong with your method. So usual debugging tricks apply: are you sure the method is actually being called? Are you sure the Match object has a Match_Status of either F or D? Put in some print statements to be sure.